# Create a div that can be repeated on every page of the report. Odoo 11

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I would like to know is it possible to create a block (div) that can be repeated on all pages of the report without it being in the header or in the footer , only for invoice report ?

```
        <template id="account.report_invoice_document">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(lang=o.partner_id.lang)" />
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div name="invoice_address" class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-7">
                            <address t-field="o.partner_id"
                                t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": True}' />
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
                  .....
          
        </template>

           <template id="report_invoice">
            <t t-call="web.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <t t-call="account.report_invoice_document" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
                    <t t-call="my_module.my_own_layout"/>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>


  

  <template id="my_own_layout">
        <!-- Multicompany -->
        <t t-if="o and 'company_id' in o">
            <t t-set="company" t-value="o.company_id"></t>
        </t>
        <t t-if="not o or not 'company_id' in o">
            <t t-set="company" t-value="res_company"></t>
        </t>
        <t t-call="my_module.my_own_layout_div"/>
        <t t-raw="0"/>
    </template>
    <template id="my_own_layout_div">
            <div>
                <h1>Here is div repeated in every page.</h1>
            </div>
    </template>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing & creating the report or getting it ? If writing , Couldn't you use an excel macro to generate these divs tags and other , and copy and paste it over your code /program .  The macro/excel sheet would need to also have your full code so you don't overwrite or loose anything . Just an idea. I'm lame I know. But that is the first thing I would look into doing given fact I am mad, only have atom, pycharm IDE and  (more )excel experience. I would see if my excel can help me programmatically to have , produce and place these div tags. Delete comment if unhelpful..